# Android version 9 DatePickerDialog dateset issue

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

My Android native application was working fine on older versions before 9. But, now on 9 on selecting date with `SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");`  date is selected as **Jan. 07 , 2020**  I don't understand from where a **.** is added after Jan which results in following error from service

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan. 07, 2020"
```

My android code

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);
            mEditTextDate.setText(getDateFormat(context).format(
                    cal.getTime()));
        }
    };

public DateFormat getDateFormat(Context context) {
        if (dateF == null)
            dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        return dateF;
    }
```

I am testing on Samsung Galaxy Tablet S6. I also tried changing Settings-->GeneralManagement --> Date and Time to Automatic date and time. But same code is working on all other tablets with MMM dd, yyyy format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Locale.ENGLISH` to get your desired date. Try below:

```
dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thanks Md. Asaduzzaman changing the Locale helped. In earlier versions  Language and Input settings was English. But in Android 9 it is English 
(Canada), English (United States) etc. Is this the reason we have to Create a SimpleDateFormat for a Specific Locale.ENGLISH